# The colors don't appear correctly when I append a grease pencil animation into another file

Tags: rendering, color, grease-pencil, render-layers

I just started using blender for a school project. I downloaded brushes and used them in my grease pencil animation. It looks fine on my screen (first photo) but when I append it into another file, it looks translucent and messy (second & third photo). The colors are not showing properly. Please help my deadline is tomorrow haha.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/. We need more information about your issue.